# OCaml Decrypt with Cryptokit

Tags: encryption, cryptography, ocaml

I am trying to understand and implement the following C# code in OCaml using the cryptokit package but I am not familiar with all of steps.

```
    public static string Decrypt(string signInKey, string apiSecret)
    {
        byte[] keyArray;
        byte[] toEncryptArray;

        //convert signInKey to byte array
        toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(signInKey);

        //convert apiSecret to byte array
        keyArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(apiSecret);

        //create decryption service provider and perform decryption
        var tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider { Key = keyArray, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 };            

        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();

        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
        tdes.Clear();

        //convert decrypted signInKey to string and return the string
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
    }
```

My best guess soo far is:

```
    let decrypted_key = 
      let open Cryptokit in
      let m = Cipher.ECB in  
      let p = Padding._8000 in
      let d = Cipher.Decrypt in
        triple_des ~mode:m ~pad:p encrypted_key d
```

Is there a good resource on how to use cryptokit/OCaml as show in the C# code above? Any directions to tutorials or information on this is much appreciated.

The OCaml documentation for cryptokit: https://github.com/vbmithr/cryptokit-sha512/blob/master/src/cryptokit.mli

Answer (score 0):

There won't be a tutorial to go from one *specific* piece of (cryptographically unsafe, ECB) C# code to a specific other runtime language.

The usage of 3DES and ECB mode is obviously correct; I cannot see if any of the input/output variables are correct as I don't know their value, and I don't see any encoding/decoding routines.

The padding is *incorrect* however. It is bit padding or ISO padding, while it should be PKCS#5/7 padding (as indicated in the C# code). You should deploy:

```
val length : scheme
```

according to the documentation [here](http://docs.camlcity.org/docs/godipkg/4.00/godi-cryptokit/doc/godi-cryptokit/html/Cryptokit.Padding.html). I don't grok OCaml though, so I cannot give an example on the usage.